# Free() pointer to Struct, inside a Struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, generic-list

I can't seem to find how to free() the sub struct.

Structs:

```
typedef struct
{
    char ID[5];
    location *loc;
} observer;

typedef struct
{
    double lat;
    double lng;
} location;
```

My Wrapper of Free() is:

```
void free_obs_list_node(void *data)
{
    free(*(observer **)data);
}
```

I can free the observer struct. I cannot free the pointer to the location Struct. This is my question: how do I free the `location` struct pointed to by `location *loc;`

I used a wrapper of `free()` as these are node's in a generic linked list.

Comment: How about `void free_observer(observer *o) { free(o->locaton); free(o); }`?

Comment: The free_observer function is declared inside my generic linked list. It takes a void* to fit my generic list. So I can't redefine the function without removing the generic design of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `free` function takes a `void*` as parameter, so that cast doesn't count.
You just need to give a pointer to the memory location you want to free:

```
free(data->loc);
```

Comment: As terribly simple as it is, this solved the issue. Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot free `loc` *after* you have freed the `observer`, but before you freed it `loc` is a fair game:

```
void free_obs_list_node(void *data) {
    observer **p = data;
    free((*p)->loc);
    free(*p);
    *p = NULL;
}
```

Of course this assumes that you are passing a pointer to a pointer to `observer` inside the `void* data`. Since the only valid reason to pass a pointer to pointer into a function that frees the pointed to pointer is to have the pointer set to `NULL`, I added the last line to null out `*p`.

It is not clear, however, why you pass `void *` instead of `observer **`.

Comment: Inside my generic linked list, I have defined the free function as taking `void* `.  This allows me to use the list with other structs without modifying it, and I only need to write the free function to fit the Structs I'm using in the given instance.

If that makes sense.

Comment: @eitharus In this case the problem is that the task cannot be accomplished generically, because the node itself has additional data members that must be freed. You could write a special-purpose function that deals specifically with this kind of linked list node, deal with specific freeing from there, and then call the generic freeing function to complete the task.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure data is not null in you code, or you can easily got a segment fault when accessing a null pointer.

I do not understand why you use a double pointer, it makes code much more complex and bug prone. Code below should work:

```
void free_obs_list_node(void *data)
{
    observer **ob = (observer **)data;// do not understand why you use a double pointer, it makes code much more complex and bug prone
    if(NULL == ob || NULL == *ob)
        return;
    if(NULL != (*ob)->loc)
        free((*ob)->loc);
    free(*ob);
}
```