# Deallocating a char pointer in Structure in C

Tags: c

I am writing a code to deallocate a char * from struct in C.

The code will be like

```
struct Name{
            char *p;
};

struct Name *name = malloc(sizeof(struct Name));
name->p = malloc(50);
```

Now I am deallocating the entire struct:
    free(name);

But I want to deallocate the char pointer i.e p.

How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot "deallocate" (`free`) a single struct field, but only the whole `struct` instance. But you can free the object it points to, if that was allocated correctly before. However, SO is no tutorial site! Read a C book! This is very basic stuff.

Comment: You need two calls of `free`. Starting from the inner fields (generally - the opposite order of that of `malloc`s).

Comment: Just do things in reverse using free instead of malloc

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant In some cases it is harmful :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free() pointer to Struct, inside a Struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382159/free-pointer-to-struct-inside-a-struct)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Seems legit!

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Another vanishing human ability ... :-(.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to deallocate name->p before deallocating name.

```
free(name->p);
free(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Especially if you are using pointers in a struct you should always memset it to 0 or call calloc. You should also check the return value of malloc. If it returns NULL then it failed to allocate.

```
struct Name {
    char *p;
};


//allocate
struct Name *name = malloc(sizeof *name);
memset(name, 0, sizeof *name);
name->p = malloc(50 * sizeof *name->p);


//deallocate
free(name->p);
free(name);
```